# Classification model penalizing the extremes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a model that classifies prices according to the increase.

High increase [1,0,0,0,0]

Increase [0,1,0,0,0]

Neutral [0,0,1,0,0]

Decrease [0,0,0,1,0]

High decrease[0,0,0,0,1]

However, the model is penalized in the same way if the error is between High increase/Increase , and between High increase/High decrease. I would like a penalty that is greater when the prediction is the opposite extreme.

```
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=n_past, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]))))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units= n_past , return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units= n_past , return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units= n_past))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 5,activation='sigmoid'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1, decay=1e-6)

regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history2 = regressor.fit(X_train,
      y_train,
      epochs=10,
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Is there a metrics that will allow me to solve my problem?

Comment: Important question - during training phase, are the predictions expressed in probability and then the cost function is computed, or are they categorized before computing the metric?
That is, are metrics computed for these scenarios [0.33, 0.67, 0, 0], or binary only [0, 1, 0, 0]?

Comment: When I do regressor.predict, the result is something like  [0.33, 0.67, 0, 0]. Is that the info you want ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: I think that this question has its place in this forum. My question is about implementation, not ML theory. (I hope I explained the theory well enough in my question)

Comment: How about custom your own loss function?